# AWS Sagemaker boto3 - getting different predictions with endpoint prediction vs running model locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, boto3, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I am very confused about my sagemaker model that is giving me strange predictions, with lots of numbers repeating (20% of predictions are the same). To troubleshoot I decided to download the model locally and test it, and it returns what I would expect.

So I'm now in a strange situation where the model gives a different prediction in Sagemaker than what it does locally.

Here are the steps I take to reproducing the error (full code below):

1. I set up an endpoint with an endpoint config, and prepare it to make predictions.
2. Then from that endpoint I get the model artifact, download this and load it into my notebook.
3. I then take a record and make predictions on it using the endpoint, and the downloaded model, and I get wildly different predictions:

> ```
> Booster object prediction: 0.9954053
>
> Classifier object prediction: 0.9954053
>
> Sagemaker endpoint prediction 0.693799495697
> ```

I converted the booster object to classifier just to ensure that was not affecting anything.

How could this happen? It's using the exact same model artifact and data, am I missing something about how loading the model works? From my understanding there's nothing else that defines an endpoint but the model artifact and the input data, which are both identical here...

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import boto3, sagemaker
import numpy as np
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer
import xgboost as xgb
import tarfile
import os
import pickle

sess = sagemaker.Session()
sm_client =  boto3.client('sagemaker')

endpoint_config_name = 'week-2-endpoint-config-prod' # using an existing endpoint config for demo
endpoint_name = 'week2-temp'

# Set up endpoint
#create_endpoint_response = sm_client.create_endpoint(
#EndpointName=endpoint_name,
#EndpointConfigName= endpoint_config_name)
#time.sleep(800)

# Get model name used by endpoint
model = sm_client.describe_endpoint_config(EndpointConfigName = endpoint_config_name)['ProductionVariants'][0]['ModelName']

# Get model artifact url
artifact_url = sm_client.describe_model(ModelName = model)['PrimaryContainer']['ModelDataUrl']

# Download model artifacts
dest = 'tempmodel.tar.gz'

boto3.client('s3').download_file(
    Bucket = 'sagemaker-us-west-2-987938178880',
    Key = artifact_url[38:],
    Filename = dest
    )

# Unpack and load the model
tf = tarfile.open(dest)
tf.extractall()

wk2_model =  pickle.load(open("xgboost-model", "rb"))
os.remove(dest)

print('Model object loaded of type:', type(wk2_model))

# Set up SKlearn wrapper classifier
regr = xgb.XGBClassifier()
regr._Booster = wk2_model

# Set up endpoint

endpoint = sagemaker.predictor.RealTimePredictor(endpoint_name, sagemaker_session=sess)
endpoint.content_type = 'text/csv'
endpoint.serializer = csv_serializer

# Test data
feats = np.asarray([[2,162.0,0.21,1,18.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.33,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,31.0,31.0,38.0,38.0,0,0,1,0.35,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999.0,-999,-999,-999,-999,24.0,55.0,56.0,30.0,62.0,64.0,755.0,1297.0,1466.0,7.0,11.0,13.0]])

print('')
print('Booster object prediction:', regr.predict_proba(feats)[:,1][0])
print('Classifier object prediction:', wk2_model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(feats))[0])
print('Sagemaker endpoint prediction', float(endpoint.predict(feats)))
```

Comment: Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Yes - it turned out it was best_ntree_limit paramter that had changed it's default value with the latest version of XGBoost

Comment: So you specified something for that parameter?

Comment: I changed model.predict(input_data, validate_features=False, ntree_limit = model.best_ntree_limit)) to model.predict(input_data, validate_features=False)) in predict_fn(input_data, model) in my entrypoint script

Comment: Will you be able to share your entry_point script? I seem to be not able to get any response out of my entry point script

Comment: Here you go. I had a lot of issues getting it to work, so there's a lot of print statements etc. Not sure if it's the best approach, but it's been working for me https://github.com/MaximusDecimusMeridius/SE/blob/master/myentryscript.py

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any immediate red flags with the code you shared.

If you continue to experience such inconsistency, it's probably worth creating a support case through the [AWS Support Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home?#/), where you can share more details about your endpoint with the SageMaker team, and have them take a closer look at your model container and its interaction with the SageMaker platform infrastructures.